# Plot_Handles - How to use if-loop with plot handles?

Tags: matlab, plot, switch-statement, handle

I'm having a bit of a problem to integrate the if-loop with plot_handles. So the program I'm writing has this structure:

It has this menufile in which you choose what you want to do (This is only a small part of it):

```
case 1

plot_handles = createPlot(plot_handles);

case 2

changeWidth(plot_handles);
```

In case 1 you'll be able to index a figure and write the function which is plotted and you're being returned to the menu.

```
function plot_handles = createPlot(plot_handles)
clc

try 
figureid = input('Input figure-ID: ');
func= input('Input function f(x): ','s');

figure(figureid);
h=ezplot(func); 
plot_handles(figureid)=h;

catch
lasterr
error('Nonvalid function!');

end
end
```

Back in the menu I enter case 2 where the thought is that it'll ask you which figure you want to edit.Once you've choosen that you're supposed to be able to edit the figures linewidth:

```
function changeWidth(plot_handles)

figureid = input('Input figure-ID: ');
h = plot_handles(figureid);

if exist(figureid)== 0 % Here's the problem, I don't know how to test if ...
% the ID is correct or not.
    error('Invalid figure-ID')


else
width=input('Input new width: ');
set(h, 'linewidth', width) 


end
```

The problem is that I don't know how to check if figure-ID is correct in the IF-loop, elsewhere I want the errormessage so be written out.

Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [`ishghandle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ishghandle.html) function?

Comment: I partly solved it using ishandle  "if ishandle(figureid)" but there's one problem. If I create two figures, 1 and 2, and I choose to edit the width of figure 1 it changes the width of figure 2 instead, it seems it always changes the latter one, any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: Try letting `figure` pick the handle for the figure instead of specifying it via `figure(figureid)`. Also, I think `ishghandle` provides stronger validation than `ishandle` here.